# After upgrading from Spring 5.2.x to 5.3.x, the error message No mapping for POST /user/updateAccount.do, Completed 404 NOT_FOUND

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

After upgrading from Spring 5.2.x to 5.3.x, the error message
`No mapping for POST /user/updateAccount.do` 
`Completed 404 NOT_FOUND`.
it was working fine when using spring  5.2.12 .RELEASE. If using spring  5.2.12 .RELEASE, this part of mapping message is : POST  “/user/updateAccount.do”, parameters={masked} mapped to com.edu.user.controller.UpdateAccountController#handlePostRequest(HttpServletRequest, HttpSession,HttpServletResponse, updateAccountForm, BindingReault, Model) . Please advise why it has error :No mapping for POST after upgrade to spring 5.3.x

Comment: Show some code?

Comment: Your post is unreadable, there is some code inbetween a sentence. Please use proper formatting to display code. Also include the URL you are calling, and the actual exception/log you have (again use proper code tags!). Finally when upgrading make sure you read the [upgrade guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x#upgrading-to-version-53).